# VBA Copy Paste suddenly repeating pasting

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I've been running this script for a while with not issues, and then today it broke. It's very basic as in I'm just filtering values from one tab and then copying and pasting them onto another tab in the top row. Suddenly though, it will paste the values and then repeat paste the values 19 more times for a total of 20 copy pastes.

```
Sheets("BSLOG").Select
Range("Q1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="1"
Range("A1:Q5000").Select
Range("A1:Q5000").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("PENDG TRADES").Select
Range("A1:Q300").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. No need to select, activate anything. In this case, these selections do not bring any benefit, they only consume Excel resources:

```
Sub testFilterCopy()
 Dim shB As Worksheet, shP As Worksheet
 Set shB = Sheets("BSLOG")
 Set shP = Sheets("PENDG TRADES")

 shB.Range("Q1").AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:="1"
 shB.Range("A1:Q5000").Copy shP.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

If you want to make the range dynamic (in terms of rows) I can show you how to initially calculate the existing number of rows and set the range to be copied according to it.

Answer (score 0):

FaneDuru is right.
You can also try this code, which I prefer more:

```
Option Base 1 'This means all array starts at 1. It is set by default at 0. Use whatever you prefer,depending if you have headers or not, etc
Sub TestFilter()
Dim shBSLOG As Worksheet
Dim shPENDG As Worksheet
Dim rngBSLOG As Range
Dim arrBSLOG(), arrCopy()
Dim RowsInBSLOG&
Dim i&, j&, k&

Set shBSLOG = Worksheets("BSLOG")
Set shPENDG = Worksheets("PENDG TRADES")

With shBSLOG
    Set rngBSLOG = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5000, 17))
End With
    RowsInBSLOG = rngBSLOG.Rows.Count
    arrBSLOG = rngBSLOG
    
    ReDim arrCopy(1 To RowsInBSLOG, 1 To 17) 'set the size of the new array as the original array
    
k = 1 'k is set to 1. This will be used to the row of the new array "arrCopy"
For i = 1 To RowsInBSLOG 'filter the array. From the row "i" = 1 to the total of rows "RowsinBSLOG
    If arrBSLOG(i, 1) = 1 Then 'if the first column of the row i is equal to 1, then...
        For j = 1 To 17
            arrCopy(k, j) = arrBSLOG(i, j) 'copy the row
        Next j
        k = k + 1 'next copy will be in a new row
    End If
Next i 'repeat

With shPENDG
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(k, 17)) = arrCopy() 'place the new array in the new sheet

End With

End Sub
```